# Enabling Hardware vlan filtering for received VLAN packets in DPDK causes performance issues

Tags: rhel7, dpdk

To enable hardware filtering by an Ethernet device of received VLAN packets tagged with a given VLAN Tag Identifier - DPDK API rte_eth_dev_vlan_filter is being used.Vlan filtering is enabled to support multiple VLAN allocation per VF . Invoking this API for every received VLAN packet is causing some performance issues like CPU overload ( 100% ) and packet forwarding delays.Is this a known issue?We are using DPDK version 18.08 and OS version RHEL 7.6.
Please suggest how to overcome this issue?

Comment: is your statement, `Using DPDK on PF vlan based packet fwd is enabled for all DPDK VF. invoking rte_eth_rx_burst is causing 100% utilization?`. are you running rte_eth_rx_burst in continuous loop `while(1) or fo(;;)`? Also please rephrase the question with code snippet on PF and VF process

Comment: please share the NIC card details, firmware. Please note `not all NIC have HW filters, hence will be implementing these features over PMD in software`. Thus affecting overall performance. Please share the details.

Comment: marking as needs improvement as @user11221955 needs to update with details